# Finding certain words in a string in the loop

Tags: c

The problem is: a user must input a word and a sequence of sentences. The output must be the only the sentences that have the given word in it (despite the symbol cases (big/small - doesn't matter))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{

    char key[25];
    char sentence[20][255];
    char* sentence_p = (char*)sentence;
    char copy[20][255];
    int kst, zero = 0, lengs;


    printf("Enter your key-word:\n");
    gets_s(key, 25);
    lengs = strlen(key);   //counting how many symbols there are in a given word without zerosymbol
    lengs--;


    puts("How many sentense you write?");
    scanf_s("%d", &kst);      //the quantity of the sentences to be written
    getchar();

    printf("Enter your sentence:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < kst; i++)
        gets_s(sentence[i], 225);    //sentence input

    for (int i = 0; i < kst; i++)
        strcpy_s(copy[i], sentence[i]);   //copying array in other array

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
        key[i] = tolower(key[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20 * 255; i++)
        *(sentence_p + i) = tolower(*(sentence_p + i));    //all the symbols are in lower case



    printf("\n\n\n\n");
    char* key_p = key;
    int z = 0;
    int j,k ;
    for (j = 0; j < 255 * kst; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < lengs; k++)
        {
            if (j != 0 && (*(sentence_p + j - 1) != ' ')) {  //element before the word is space
                z = 0;
                continue;
            }

            if ((*((key_p)+k) == *((sentence_p + j) + k)))  //word=word
                z++;
            else
                z = 0;
        }
            if (*(sentence_p + j + k + 1) != ' ') {//element after the word is space 
                z = 0;
                continue;
            }


            if (z == lengs - 1) {
                int k = j / 20;
                puts(copy[k]);
                continue;
            }

        z = 0;
    }


    if (zero == 0)
        puts("Not found ");   
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The troubles that I have are:
1) The output is always "not found" 
2) Or it outputs symbols beyond the array

Comment: Problems like these are usually best solved using debugger.

Answer (score 4):

whatever you do, this code will always output "Not found":

```
int kst, zero = 0, lengs;

// a lot of irrelevant stuff skipped

if (zero == 0)
    puts("Not found ");
```

Comment: ...good catch ;)